# How to enable C++ multithreading?

Tags: c++, c++11

I've been trying multithreaded C++. I installed the new Dev C++ 5.4.1 and added `-std=c++11` to the compiler options. Then I added `#include <thread>` somewhere in my source code, and `std::thread mythread (some_func)`.

When I compile the source file, I get a compiler error "thread defined in this scope".

What do I have to do to have it working?

Comment: AFAIK MinGW (the compiler Dev-C++ uses) has no support for standard library threads yet.

Comment: Are you sure, that error message is _"thread defined in this scope"_?

Comment: what if I use g++ on the command line?

Comment: Please post more detailed information.

Comment: ok it reads that thread does not define a name

Comment: please paste the exact and complete compiler error here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Official build of MinGW (that compiler Dev-C++ uses) has no support for standard library threads now.

You can use `boost::thread` as a drop in replacement (API is similiar enough) or use Microsoft Visual C++, or try programming with g++ on Linux (this is what I have done recently, using a virtual machine).

Comment: this is not true. Support is present, just not enabled in all binarie releases

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the correct package of Mingw like sad here:
http://gameprog.it/articles/90/c-11-getting-started-on-windows

the package is found at:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/

The article is about code::blocks, but you can easily setup DevC++ too. Just pay a bit care about file names.

There's no longer need for boost threads at all. (Boost still remain a very good library and I encourage you to take a deeper look, but that is out of topic)